# Ifconfig in Ubuntu 18.04 is not working

Tags: network-manager, 18.04, ifconfig

Recently I have switched from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and I have found that `ifconfig` is not working in Ubuntu 18.04.

So what alternative does Ubuntu 18.04 offer and what is the reason for removing/replacing `ifconfig`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `ifconfig` command and also the `route` command are obsolete and are replaced by the `ip` command which comes with the `iproute2` package.

There are some more tools that got replaced. A good starting point to get an overview is [here](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/07/07/if-youre-still-using-ifconfig-youre-living-in-the-past).